# Android: GCM CCS Server implementation

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, google-cloud-messaging

I have been looking forward to implement a chat application in android. Being a beginner,I had no clue where to begin with. But,then i came across http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/. The thing is there are two codes here. Am well aware on how to implement a GCM CCS CLient. But,can anyone tell me to how to implement the GCM CCS Server code given in the website?
I mean..well...what should be done... in a step by step manner?
Note : I have searched thoroughly but couldn't find any clear tutorial in the internet.Even a tiny amount of help is appreciated!

Comment: That tutorial no server side code, and no reply for any question posted below.. plz check this: http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/4/